# C# Winforms - can't see my table when creating a data source

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, oracle11g

I recently installed Oracle XE 11g on my machine and am trying to make a connection to it from a winform project.

I have created a new table in sqldeveloper, the connection settings I used in sql developer are:

connection_name : xe

User : SYSTEM

password : ********

host : localhost

port : 1521

SID : xe

In my `WinForms` project i have created a simple `gridview` and am trying to use the wizard to create a new data course but when I do, I get a bunch of tables but I cannot see my table I created.

Also, in sql developer i cannot see the `JOBS`, `JOBS_HISTORY`, etc tables but in the data source wizard they appear in the list of available tables.

I suspect I have somehow made a connection to the wrong database! If someone could kindly tell me what I'm doing horribly wrong I would be very grateful as I'm hitting my head against the wall on this as it does not make much sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i stupdily didnt realise i needed to create a new users and then create a table under that user.

Once i did that i could see the table in the data source in visual studio. I'm guessing tables owned by the System user cannot be seen to other people/application and is only visible to the administrator?